# Apache Mina Ftplet - onUploadStart is not saving the file

Tags: java, apache-mina

When overriding the ftplet's onUploadStart method for storing the file content into a database, the uploaded file is not saving in the filesystem as supposed.
The ftpclient is receiving the correct response but the file is not saved.

```
@Override
public FtpletResult onUploadStart(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request) throws FtpException, IOException {
    log.debug("onUploadStart");

    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataConnectionFactory connectionFactory = session.getDataConnection();
    session.write(new DefaultFtpReply(150, "Getting data connection."));
    try {
        DataConnection dataConnection = connectionFactory.openConnection();

        if (dataConnection == null) {
            session.write(new DefaultFtpReply(425, "Cannot open data connection."));
            return FtpletResult.SKIP;
        }
        dataConnection.transferFromClient(session, outputStream);

        String uploadedContent = outputStream.toString();

        insertInDatabase(uploadedContent);
        session.write(new DefaultFtpReply(226, "Data transfer okay."));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.write(new DefaultFtpReply(551, "Data transfer failed."));
        return FtpletResult.SKIP; 
    } finally {
        connectionFactory.closeDataConnection();
        outputStream.close();

    }
    return FtpletResult.SKIP; 
}
```

The read content is stored in the database but after that operation I got a NullPointerException when the FTPserver is trying to continue the STOR operation:

```
017-12-29 10:52:16 [pool-4-thread-1] WARN  
org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnectionFactory  - 
FtpDataConnection.getDataSocket()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnectionFactory.createDataSocket(IODataConnectionFactory.java:354)
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnectionFactory.openConnection(IODataConnectionFactory.java:257)
at org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.STOR.execute(STOR.java:133)
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpHandler.messageReceived(DefaultFtpHandler.java:211)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpHandlerAdapter.messageReceived(FtpHandlerAdapter.java:62)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:858)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter.messageReceived(FtpLoggingFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.messageReceived(CommonEventFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:398)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:234)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:770)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:762)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:704)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-12-29 10:52:16 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG 
org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.STOR  - Exception getting the input data stream
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnectionFactory.createDataSocket(IODataConnectionFactory.java:354)
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnectionFactory.openConnection(IODataConnectionFactory.java:257)
at org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.STOR.execute(STOR.java:133)
at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpHandler.messageReceived(DefaultFtpHandler.java:211)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpHandlerAdapter.messageReceived(FtpHandlerAdapter.java:62)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:858)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter.messageReceived(FtpLoggingFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.messageReceived(CommonEventFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:398)
at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:234)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:770)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:762)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:704)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same exception, with your code and ftpserver-core-1.1.1 - but only when I leave onUploadStart()-method without FtpletResult.SKIP. Thus I am unsure why this happens.

Would it be an option for you to overwrite onUploadEnd(), read your data from the uploaded file and delete it afterwards? This should avoid the problem.